# Reading Bitmap from another activity -> Empty Image

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

**Background:**
To give a bit of background ⇒ the app should simply show the user an area (SignatureActivity / SignatureCanvasView) to put a signature. I found a snippet, which works pretty well to draw in.

**Issue:** Trying to retrieve the bitmap in the MainActivity to show it in an ImageView shows an empty Image. Also writing the retrieved Bitmap creates an png file, which is pretty much empty, since it has even not a background color.

That's how it's done in MainActivity:

```
    private void insertSignature(){
        ivSign.setImageBitmap(signature);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if(requestCode == SIGNATURE_REQUEST){
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                signature = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data.getByteArrayExtra("SignatureBitmap"), 0, data.getByteArrayExtra("SignatureBitmap").length);
                //signature = (Bitmap) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("SignatureBitmap");
                if(signature != null){
                    insertSignature();
                    Log.e("ActivityResult: ", "SignatureActivity finished with RESULT_OK");
                }
            }else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
                Log.e("ActivityResult: ", "SignatureActivity was cancelled");
            }else{
                Log.e("ActivityResult", "Unknown activity result!");
            }
        }

    }
```

That is the code for the view (SignatureCanvasView), which maintains the signature functionality:

```
public class SignatureCanvasView extends View {
    public int width;
    public int height;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Canvas mCanvas;
    private Path mPath;
    Context context;
    private Paint mPaint;
    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOLERANCE = 5;

    public SignatureCanvasView(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(c, attrs);
        context = c;

        // we set a new Path
        mPath = new Path();

        // and we set a new Paint with the desired attributes
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(2f);
    }

    public byte[] getBitmap() {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

        return byteArray;
    }


    // override onSizeChanged
    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        // your Canvas will draw onto the defined Bitmap
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    }

    // override onDraw
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        // draw the mPath with the mPaint on the canvas when onDraw
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }

    // when ACTION_DOWN start touch according to the x,y values
    private void startTouch(float x, float y) {
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    // when ACTION_MOVE move touch according to the x,y values
    private void moveTouch(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOLERANCE || dy >= TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }

    public void clearCanvas() {
        mPath.reset();
        invalidate();
    }

    // when ACTION_UP stop touch
    private void upTouch() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
    }

    //override the onTouchEvent
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                startTouch(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                moveTouch(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                upTouch();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The getBitmap()-method of the SignatureCanvasView is called in SignatureActivity to put it as extra, before finishing:

```
public class SignatureActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //...
    public void Save(){
        this.getIntent().putExtra("SignatureBitmap",scw.getBitmap());
        setResult(RESULT_OK,this.getIntent());
        finish();
    }
    //...
}
```

I appreaciate any hints and suggestions to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are drawing `Path` onto `canvas` attached with `SignatureCanvasView`, not on the canvas attached with `Bitmap mBitmap`.

```
// override onDraw
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    // draw the mPath with the mPaint on the canvas when onDraw
    // canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    boolean drawPathTwice = true;
    if (drawPathTwice) {
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint); // this will be visible to user
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);// draw path onto canvas attached with mBitmap
        // drawing path 2 times(wasting resources).
    } else {
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);  // draw path onto canvas attached with mBitmap
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);
        // we have drawn path onto bitmap canvas, so view's canvas will be
        // empty, to give touch feedback we can draw our bitmap containing
        // path onto view's canvas.
    }
}
```

Better option would be to have a class scope boolean which will control
     drawing on bitmap (you can set it to true in upTouch() method).

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

    if (drawOnBitmap) {  // this code will be executed only on ACTION_UP
        // event
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);  // draw path onto canvas attached with mBitmap
        drawOnBitmap = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was aware of using the canvas of it and tried to save it in mCanvas too but I don‘t understand why this functions and not the attempt what I‘ve tried.
I had tried to do mCanvas = canvas; after the line, where canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint) was called and for some reason, your code with drawPath both in canvas and mCanvas works. Overwrite the mCanvas with canvas after drawing doesn't work. Maybe you have a proper explanation for it. Nevertheless: Thank you so much.

Comment: I have updated my answer and assigning bitmap canvas to view's canvas will not work because after `mCanvas = canvas` your bitmap is still attached to mCanvas and stuff will appear onto Bitmap if you draw it on its canvas.

Comment: Hey there. Could you maybe help me to fix the clearCanvas()-method.
If I draw, clear and draw something again, the cleared drawing are still on the returned bitmap.
e.g. draw X, clearCanvas(), drawed y & z
the canvas in the SignatureView shows 'y&z', however the returned Bitmap in MainActivity shows 'Xy&z', so the clearCanvas()-method clears just the View in SignatureView.

Comment: nvm. solved the issue, by moving mCanvas.drawPath(mPath,mPaint) to getBitmap()-method. On that way, the drawings get drawn just before retrieving the bitmap. I think, it's also more performant to do so.

Comment: Yes, drawing in `getBitmap()` method is best performance wise.